# Grant access to multiple users in Google Cloud Repository?

Tags: git, repository, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-repository

I have recently created a repository in Google Cloud Repository under a project in my Google Cloud Platform account and generated manual git credentials to clone it and commit changes. Everything is working fine here. Now I want to grant access to my team members, allowing them to clone it and contribute their changes. I am unable to find any options in google cloud platform. I have created a user in IAM and granted him administrative access over repositories but I could not find any option to generate git credentials for them.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Is this possible? I could do the same in AWS easily, I am sure it must be possible in GCP as well.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone you add a member of your project will have access to your CSR repos.